# how does this .net code work, can you use pseudo code to explain?

Tags: .net

I have the .net code below and I am trying to figure out how it works, can someone please explain how it works using pseudo code or English whichever is the best way?

```
namespace Export
{
  public class Licencing
  {
    public string licensingstr;
    public string regvalue;

    public bool IsLicenced(string ChkHdr)
    {
      if (ChkHdr == "Live System")
        return true;
      int num = 0;
      for (int index = 0; index < ChkHdr.Length; ++index)
        num += (int) ChkHdr[index];
      return this.GetRegChkSum() == num * 31;
    }

    public void SetRegChkSum(string ChkSum)
    {
      RegistryKey subKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true).CreateSubKey("Professional Services \\Configuration");
      subKey.SetValue("MaxRows", (object) ChkSum);
      subKey.Close();
    }

    private int GetRegChkSum()
    {
      RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Professional Services \\Configuration");
      if (registryKey == null)
        return 0;
      object obj = registryKey.GetValue("MaxRows");
      if (obj == null)
        return 0;
      this.regvalue = Convert.ToString(obj);
      this.regvalue = this.regvalue.Substring(1, this.regvalue.Length - 2);
      registryKey.Close();
      return int.Parse(this.regvalue, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully it's not confidential code :P Also, its C# more so then .net.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example of copy protection system as far as i can see.

var licenseChecker = new Licencing();

licenseChecker.IsLicenced("Live System");

//Will return true, just a mockup for testing puproses

licenseChecker.IsLicenced("key");

// Here you get the value for sum of int values for evey char (107 for k), (101 for e), (121 for y) and multiply it for 31. 329*31 for the text example

// Then you try to get value from registry key, and check if the substring of it is the hex value for 329*31.